# Entity Framework 4, dynamic proxies with AsyncController in ASPNET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using the following method in my application which uses AsyncController, which retrieves (in the using a dynamic proxy if I don't use the foreach and use something like 
newMessageList = myMessages.ToList();.

I need to get in newMessageList a List not of dynamic proxy, because if not when the View tries to parse the result it throws an HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error).
Is there any way I can avoid the use of the foreach to iterate over each property of myMessage and just avoid to creation of the Dynamic Proxies for it? (but just here, not for the entire application).

```
   private class MyAsyncResult : IAsyncResult
    {
        private static int mCount = 0;
        private readonly CheckForNewMessagesResponse mCheckForNewMessagesResponse;
        private readonly Thread mThread;
        private readonly AutoResetEvent mWait;

        public MyAsyncResult(CheckForNewMessagesResponse checkForNewMessagesResponse)
        {
            List<Message> newMessageList = null; 
            using (var ctx = new Server.Model.ServerPOCOs())
            {
                mCheckForNewmyMessagesResponse = checkForNewmyMessagesResponse;
                newmyMessageList = new List<myMessage>();

                var myMessages = from myMessage in ctx.myMessages
                                  where !myMessage.read
                                  orderby myMessage.ReceptionDate
                                  select myMessage;


                foreach (myMessage message in myMessages)
                {
                    myMessage um = new myMessage();
                    um.concept1 = message.concept1;
                    um.concept2 = message.concept2;

                    newmyMessageList.Add(um); 
                }
            }

            mWait = new AutoResetEvent(false);

            mThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));

                checkForNewmyMessagesResponse(newmyMessageList);

                mWait.Set();
            }));

            mThread.Start();
        }
```

Thanks in advance. Guillermo.

Comment: Have you tried calling  ).ToList();   at the end of your Linq query

Comment: yep, it retrieves a list of dynamic proxies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
using (var ctx = new Server.Model.ServerPOCOs())
{
    ctx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

    newMessages = (from myMessage in ctx.myMessages
                   where !myMessage.read
                   orderby myMessage.ReceptionDate
                   select myMessage).ToList();
}
```

Edit: Sample modified for ObjectContext API.

Comment: Thanks Ladislav! I just needed to change your code a little...
ctx.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
With that it worked!

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right. My code was for DbContext API but you mentioned that you are using EFv4 (ObjectContext API). The property is called `ContextOptions` - I modified my answer.